# Какие форматы данных распространены для обмена GPS-треками и прочей географической информацией?

Tags: android, gps

Мне интересно, как в разных приложениях, особенно в приложениях социальных сетей, сделан обмен геоданными? К примеру, надо мне человеку показать куда проехать (точка), или КАК проехать (трек или существующий GPX-лог), каким образом я могу передать эту информацию? Точнее, в каких форматах обычно такое происходит?

Платформа Android. Поставить сотню приложений и посмотреть как сделано, а потом сделать аналогично - это наверное самый правильный вариант, но он достаточно долгий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый удобный, на мой взгляд, и он же самый распространенный (сколько не было программ, все понимали) - как раз GPX. Основан на XML (для программиста удобен), содержит всё, что надо, при желании - расширяем для собственных нужд.

Comment: А всяким вконтактикам и однокласникам его скормить можно? Или из них получить его?

Comment: "Скормить" - это что значит? Просто дать скачать? - Да. Или поделиться в каком-то особо изощренном виде? :)

Comment: Ну вот допустим я нахожусь по координатам 1.2345 северной широты и 6.7890 восточной долготы. Я хочу, чтобы  мой собеседник, который пользуется каким-либо способом связи (фейсбук, вконтакт и прочая гадость), получил эти координаты, но не как текст, а как некую рабочую кнопку, по которой он смог бы открыть у себя карту и проложить маршрут до нужных коодинат. Многие приложения в интенте просто шарят ссылку на свой сайт, но у меня ссылок нет, приложение независимо. Можно еще картинку отправить, но картинка еще менее полезна, чем простой текст. Как-то ведь это все работает? Люди ведь обмениваются?

Comment: Понятно. Я пользовался этим подходом - создал страничку у себя на сайте, а потом обновлял GPX-файл: http://webmap-blog.ru/bez-rubriki/otobrazhenie-na-yandeks-kartax-fajlov-v-formate-gpx  Правда, в фейсбуке как кнопку не отобразить, но как ссылку - вполне. Перезалил GPX - маршрут обновился.

Comment: Вот и все делают через веб-ссылку, по которой откроется неизвестно что. А мне надо без сайтов. Ну, я уже морально готов делать скриншоты, причем в том числе как GPX

Comment: Есть такой вот http://vialatm.com/home_ru.html  сервис, бесплатен для персонального пользования, вроде как работает с фейсбуком. Но я так в нем и не разобрался.